# Open popup using if else

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new in iOS development. I come from Android background.
I want to implement a `popup`. I made a home page and it has a submit button.
The submit button has two functions. If the user is using the app for the first time then the button will redirect it to the OTP screen (not segue - its an external library - it creates viewController via programming)
and if the user has already registered his number then the button should open up the popup.
In my case i have made a custom popup using viewController and I can open it by connecting the button and the popup viewController(kind = present modally) but it always opens up the popup.

For reference i want to achieve this

```
if (registeredUser()) 
    //show popup
else 
    openOTP()
```

**UPDATE**

I solved this issue by connecting My homepage ViewController to the PopUp ViewController(remember don't drag from the views inside ViewController,Drag from the ViewController itself) then in the code whenever you need to use the popup just just this

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueName", sender: (Any).self)
```

also go to segue and then put some Identifier, In my case it was segueName

Answer (score -1):

I connected My homepage `ViewController` to the PopUp ViewController(remember don't drag from the views inside ViewController,Drag from the ViewController itself)
then in the code whenever you need to use the popup just just this

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueName", sender: (Any).self)
```

also go to segue and then put some Identifier, In my case it was segueName

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer, or is it it further information to be added to the question ? (If the latter, then please edit it into your question and delete this.)

Comment: This is posted in the answer section so obviously this is meant to be an answer

Comment: @Sam Please consider editing your answer to explain how this addresses the issue you had, for the benefit of others with similar issues. As it is, your answer has been flagged as low quality. (Also, FYI just because something is posted as an answer doesn't mean that was the intention - the review queues include many new and low-rep users who add answers instead of updating their question.)